# Why is Eisav mentioned as "Ish" twice?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

Some love this kind of details:

> "... וַיְהִי עֵשָׂו אִישׁ יֹדֵעַ צַיִד אִישׁ שָׂדֶה ...׃ - .. Esau became a skillful hunter, a man of the outdoors; [Genesis.25.27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.25.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)"

In Hebrew, one can say it as "איש שדה יודע ציד", however, the word איש appears in the verse twice.

It appears that the two descriptions are unrelated, and he was both a hunter and outdoorsy.

Do the commentators address this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I have an answer which works only as far as the sentence structure, but not if you care about the grammatical repetition.

The [Sifsei Chachomim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Siftei_Chakhamim%2C_Genesis.25.27.2&lang2=bi) explains that the descriptions of Esav mirror Yaakov's and are used to convey the polar opposites. He writes:

> Entrap and deceive his father with his mouth - [Rashi knows this] because it says יודע ציד, implying that it requires wisdom. Otherwise it would mean the same as, “A man of the field.” Furthermore, [Rashi knows this] because איש ציד is the opposite of איש תם, just as איש שדה is the opposite of יושב אוהלים. And if איש ציד meant trapping animals, it would not be the opposite of איש תם. A wholesome man could also trap animals! (Sefaria translation and notation)

So perhaps we can answer that the first איש יודע ציד is used to demonstrate the he was a man that connived and tricked his father which mirrors the use of איש תם used by Yaakov, i.e. a man who was 'simple'. Then the second use of איש is to demonstrate what they did with their time. So איש שדה by Esav is used to mirror Yaakov's practise of sitting in tents i.e. whereas Yaakov's occupation was sitting in tents, Esav's sole practise was to be a man of the field.